# Can i set exact width and height for the borders around my record field?

Tags: html, css, netsuite, markup, bfo

When I apply this pdf to a transaction, the borders collapse and just cover the $ value it is pulling in.  It needs to be a set height and width so the boxes look similar on the table.

I've tried the Box sizing: border-box fix but I couldn't get it to work.  Any ideas, maybe I had the block wrong still.

```
<tr style = "padding-bottom: 9px;">
    <td><b>Custom Field:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
    <td><span style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 30px">${record.customfield}</span></td>
  </tr>
    <tr style = "padding-bottom: 9px;">
    <td><b>Custom Field:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
    <td><span style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 30px;">${record.customfield}</span></td>
  </tr>
```